# C printf indentation issue

Tags: c, printf

I am looking to correctly indent the below, I want that `DG1, DG2, DG3, DG4` should be in the same column, Is there an optimal way to it ? Thanks, any pointers or help would be appreciated.

---

```
      Test                                                                 DG1                                                                 
                                                                       DG2                                                                     
                                                                       DG3                                                                     
                                                                       DG3
```

sh-4.2# ^C

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%-64s\t%s\n", "List", "Bindings");
    printf("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");

    const char *curr_dl_result[] = {
        [0] = "DG1",
        [1] = "DG2",
        [2] = "DG3",
        [3] = "DG3",
    };
    int dg_count = 4;
    int  j = 0;
    char buff[1024];
    printf("%s", "Test");
    if(dg_count) {
        unsigned char is_print_done = 0;     
        for(j = 0; j < dg_count; j++) {     
            printf("%78s\n", (curr_dl_result[j]));
            is_print_done = 1;
        }
    } else {
        printf("%78s\n","-" );
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Dont forget that printf and sprintf returns the amount of chars printed so you can use that number to add the correct number of spaces at the end of the line before your "DG1"-strings and get a nicer output.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, will try that.

Comment: Thanks to everybody for the quick help, I will probably go for the following:                                                            if(j == 0){
    int space=74; // 78 - prev_print_len
    printf("%*s\n",space, curr_dl_result[j]);
}

Comment: now don't forget to mark a answer as solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use the fact that printf returns the number of chars printed, 
and then pad with spaces before printing the last string.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void my_out(const char* str1, const char* str2)
{
    int len = printf("%s", str1);
    int i;
    for( i=len ; i<60 ; i++ )
    {
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("%s\n", str2);
}

int main()
{

    my_out("List", "Bindings");
    printf("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");

    const char *curr_dl_result[] = {
        [0] = "DG1",
        [1] = "DG2",
        [2] = "DG3",
        [3] = "DG3",
    };

    my_out("Test",curr_dl_result[1]);
    my_out("Test  eee",curr_dl_result[2]);
    my_out("Test 22",curr_dl_result[3]);
    return 0;
}
```

This will print:

```
List                                                        Bindings
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test                                                        DG2
Test  eee                                                   DG3
Test 22                                                     DG3
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you change

`printf("%s", "Test");` to

```
printf("%s\n", "Test");
```

This will print and indent DG1, DG2, DG3, DG4 correctly and will print a line after test **if you don't mind.**
See this http://ideone.com/ZhOlhF

Answer (score 0):

E.g. replacing the `printf` inside `for` by this `if` should do the trick:

```
if (j == 0)
     printf("%74s\n", (curr_dl_result[j])); // account for "Test" (4 chars) on same line
else
     printf("%78s\n", (curr_dl_result[j]));
```

Comment: Well, "test" is just an example, it could be anything, Was trying to find out if there is a inbuilt way to it.

Comment: @user2766839 It's quite trivial to generalize starting from the observation that `78 - strlen("Test") == 74`. Please be sure to state in your question(s) what you hope to find by asking them in the first place :)

Answer (score 0):

How about some dynamic allocation (still has some hard coded stuff but more generalizable):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%-64s\t%s\n", "List", "Bindings");
    printf("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");

     const char *curr_dl_result[] = {
        [0] = "DG1",
        [1] = "DG2",
        [2] = "DG3",
        [3] = "DG3",
     };
     int dg_count = 4;
     int  j = 0;
     int pos = printf("%s", "Test");
     if(dg_count) {
         unsigned char is_print_done = 0;
         for(j = 0; j < dg_count; j++) {
             char *spacer = malloc(74-pos*sizeof(char));
             memset(spacer, ' ', 74-pos);
             printf("%s", spacer);
             printf("%s\n", (curr_dl_result[j]));
             is_print_done = 1;
             pos = 0;
             free(spacer);
         }
     }
     else {
         printf("%78s\n","-" );
     }
    return 0;
}
```